# Download Log files from Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am having my bucket on Amazon S3 where I have uploaded certains files.

I have a sort public visitation on the page.

Is there any way to get the all visitations in log file
or Can I download the log file from the Amazon?

Answer (score 2):

You can create logging for S3 bucket at the creation of bucket itself also after creating bucket. You need to specify the path for log file to store.You can refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/ManagingBucketLogging.html for steps.

Comment: Using AWSSDK I was able to download the log created by public visitation.